# Python command to open CMD and run a complex query with multiple inputs

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python so please go easy on me.
I'm trying to create a script that will take several inputs from a user, run openSSL in CMD and output a .key and .csr file. My code opens CMD properly but doesn't seem to like the command I'm trying to execute.

```
import os
openssl = str(r'C:\"Program Files"\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe')
command = str(' req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout ')
keyfile = str(r"C:\\Users\\chron\\Desktop\\Python practice\\SSL_cert_key.key")
csrfile = str(r" -out C:\\Users\\chron\\Desktop\\Python practice\\SSL_cert_csr.csr")
    os.system('start cmd /k' + openssl + command + keyfile + csrfile)
```

When this is run CMD shows me that the command stopped executing after req

> req: Use -help for summary.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with subprocess.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd', '/k', r'C:\"Program Files"\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe', ...])
```

Every time you use space in your string, put it in another position.

Comment: Unfortunately this results in a different error 
`[WinError 2] The System cannot find the file specified.`